# Angular Material Layout issue with flex

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I have an issue with AMD layout at the smaller resolutions. At the small resolutions Widget1 doesn't fill entire div. I tried with the layout-fill atribute, but doesn't work.
Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ja2RgH6aYq204EdaUSPC?p=preview).

```
<div layout="row" layout-md="column" layout-sm="column" layout-margin="">
  <section class="widget md-whiteframe-z1 ng-isolate-scope md-cyan-theme" ng-class="{'widget-overlay-title': overlayTitle}" ng-attr-layout="{{widgetLayout}}" content-padding="" flex="66">
        <div class="panel-heading">Widget1<span flex=""></span></div>
  </section>

  <section class="widget md-whiteframe-z1 ng-isolate-scope md-cyan-theme" ng-class="{'widget-overlay-title': overlayTitle}" ng-attr-layout="{{widgetLayout}}" content-padding="" flex="32">
    <div class="panel-heading">Widget2<span flex=""></span></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: your flex="66" prevent it to take the whole line.   Is that what you want ? : http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx5ytWx6jQFpdCYWPn76?p=preview

Comment: I want to display Widget1 larger then Widget2 (70:30) on larger resolution

Comment: I've update my plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/Sx5ytWx6jQFpdCYWPn76?p=preview use flex-gt-lg to use a specific flex only on wider screen. look at : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/options

Comment: Great, I've defined large and medium screen and it's look ok now http://plnkr.co/edit/9uqBZEEcf0pzhz5TojPG?p=preview